# D3.js defs and url() does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

This code is a part of my project that I am trying to make force-layout graph in it. All links between nodes should have a marker that I make them (the markers) by the means of defs patterns.
In this code I expect to see defined markers in `defs` where I have called them by `url(#id)` but I do not see it while I get no error. It was working before but suddenly all `defs` has been disabled in my code.
Here you see the result svg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.link.flow {
    opacity: 1!important;
    /*stroke-width: 1.5px;*/
}

#licensing {
    fill: green;
}

.link.flow.licensing {
    stroke: green;
}

.link.flow.resolved {
    stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle.flow {
    fill: #ff2575;
    stroke: #ff2575;
    /*stroke-width: 1.5px;*/
}

text.flow {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

path.link.flow {
    fill: none;
 stroke: blue;
}




</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var maxWeight = 0;
var maxSize = 0;

//  new graph: start
var margin = 10;
var width = 455,
 height = 350;

var svgMaster = d3.select("body").append("svg") //  initiate svg
 .attr("id","flow")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .style("margin-right",margin+"px")
 .style("margin-left",margin+"px");

var svg = svgMaster.append('svg:g')
 .attr('id','groupFlow');

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
 node = svg.selectAll(".node");  //  nodes and links
// :end new graph

var jsonData = {
 "nodes": [
  {"username": "S_Christophorus", "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952", "last_name":
   "Christophorus", "first_name": "Stanly", "avatar": "/media/avatars/C02.png", "person_id": "556431f3cdfa661108325774"
  , "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1a8e"},
  {"username": "A_Field", "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952"
  , "last_name": "Field", "first_name": "Abdul", "avatar": "/media/avatars/B01.png", "person_id": "556431f3cdfa6611083257f6"
  , "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1b94"}, 
  {"username": "B_Hugh", "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952"
  , "last_name": "Hugh", "first_name": "Beale", "avatar": "/media/avatars/B02.png", "person_id": "556431f3cdfa6611083257f7"
  , "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1b96"}, 
  {"username": "M_Kennedy", "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952"
  , "last_name": "Kennedy", "first_name": "Mordy", "avatar": "/media/avatars/B05.png", "person_id": "556431facdfa661108327e21"
  , "id": "55641128cdfa6618acdd9fed"}
 ], 
 "edges": [
  {"source": 0, "target": 1, "weight": 1.5}, 
  {"source": 2, "target": 0, "weight": 46.5}, 
  {"source": 0, "target": 2, "weight": 6.0}, 
  {"source": 2, "target": 1, "weight": 1.5}, 
  {"source": 2, "target": 3, "weight": 3.0}
 ]
}


/*
 * refresh graph based on given data
 */
var refreshForceFlow = function(json){
 clearGraphFlow();
 var maxWeight = 0;
 
    for(var edgeIndex = 0; edgeIndex < json.edges.length; edgeIndex++){
      if(json.edges[edgeIndex].weight > maxWeight) maxWeight = json.edges[edgeIndex];
      }
   console.log(json);
 var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(d3.values(json.nodes))
  .links(json.edges)
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(60)
  .charge(-300)
  .on("tick", tickFlow)
  .start();

 // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
 svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(json.edges)
  .enter().append("marker")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return ("weight_"+d.weight).replace(".","_"); })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 13)    //  15
  .attr("refY", 0)    //  -1.5
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d){
   var color = 'FF';
   var c = Math.floor((d.weight*99)/maxWeight);
   c = 100 - c;
   if( c < 10) c = '0'+c;
   color = c + color;
   color = c + color;
   //console.log('#'+color);
   return '#'+color;
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d){
   var color = 'FF';
   var c = Math.floor((d.weight*99)/maxWeight);
   c = 100 - c;
   if( c < 10) c = '0'+c;
   color = c + color;
   color = c + color;
   //console.log('#'+color);
   return '#'+color;
  })
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

 var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
  .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "link flow "; })
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
   var res = 1 + ((d.weight * 2.5) / maxWeight);
   return res + 'px';
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d){
   var color = 'FF';
   var c = Math.floor((d.weight*99)/maxWeight);
   c = 100 - c;
   if( c < 10) c = '0'+c;
   color = c + color;
   color = c + color;
   //console.log('#'+color);
   return '#'+color;
  })
  .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + ("weight_"+d.weight).replace(".","_") + ")"; });

 var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .attr("class", "flow")
  .call(force.drag);

 var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "flow")
  .attr("x", 8)
  .attr("y", ".31em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.username; });

 // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
 function tickFlow() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
 }

 function linkArc(d) {
  var tx = d.target.x - 0;
  var ty = d.target.y - 0;
  var sx = d.source.x - 0;
  var sy = d.source.y - 0;

  var dx = tx - sx,
   dy = ty - sy,
   dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
 }

 function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
 }
};  //  end of function

/*
 * clear gragh
 */
var clearGraphFlow = function(){
 svg.selectAll("g").remove();
 svg.selectAll("defs").remove();
};

refreshForceFlow(jsonData);

</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in the HTML? Are the defs there and properly defined?  Do the marker-end attributes also look OK in your HTML?

Comment: Yes I do. It has defined properly. I will post it in the question.

Comment: Hi, did  my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I notice in the edit history that you changed the `source` and `target` members from text to numeric, deleted the reference to the out of scope event handler `contextmenu`, these were fixed in my second answer and that, along with my original answer fixed most of your problems.  I suggest you ***accept*** the first answer since it was central to the topic of your question.

Comment: By the way, your calculation of `maxWeight` is currently broken and that's why your links are all 1px stroke width.  You could fix it by changing it to `if(json.edges[edgeIndex].weight > maxWeight) maxWeight = json.edges[edgeIndex].weight;`  I assume its a typo?  This type of bug is another good reason to use the `d3.max` function as recomended in my second answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I pointed out in my previous answer was the reason for the refs issue, but there were other problems as well through-out the code.  Please see corrected code below...

```js
//debug panel///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var update = d3.select("#update")
  .on("click", (function() {
    var dataSet = false;
    return function() {
      refreshForceFlow(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData[(dataSet = !dataSet, +dataSet)])))
    }
  })());
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var maxWeight = 0;
var maxSize = 0;

//  new graph: start
var margin = 10;
var width = 500,
  height = 150;

var svgMaster = d3.select("body").append("svg") //  initiate svg
  .attr("id", "flow")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("margin-right", margin + "px")
  .style("margin-left", margin + "px");

var svg = svgMaster.append('svg:g')
  .attr('id', 'groupFlow');

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
  node = svg.selectAll(".node"); //  nodes and links

// :end new graph

var jsonData = [{
  "nodes": [{
    "username": "S_Christophorus",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Christophorus",
    "first_name": "Stanly",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/C02.png",
    "person_id": "556431f3cdfa661108325774",
    "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1a8e"
  }, {
    "username": "A_Field",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Field",
    "first_name": "Abdul",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/B01.png",
    "person_id": "556431f3cdfa6611083257f6",
    "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1b94"
  }, {
    "username": "B_Hugh",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Hugh",
    "first_name": "Beale",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/B02.png",
    "person_id": "556431f3cdfa6611083257f7",
    "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1b96"
  }, {
    "username": "M_Kennedy",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Kennedy",
    "first_name": "Mordy",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/B05.png",
    "person_id": "556431facdfa661108327e21",
    "id": "55641128cdfa6618acdd9fed"
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "source": "0",
    "target": "1",
    "weight": 1.5
  }, {
    "source": "2",
    "target": "0",
    "weight": 46.5
  }, {
    "source": "0",
    "target": "2",
    "weight": 6.0
  }, {
    "source": "2",
    "target": "1",
    "weight": 1.5
  }, {
    "source": "2",
    "target": "3",
    "weight": 3.0
  }]
}, {
  "nodes": [{
    "username": "A_Field",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Christophorus",
    "first_name": "Stanly",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/C02.png",
    "person_id": "556431f3cdfa661108325774",
    "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1a8e"
  }, {
    "username": "B_Hugh",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Field",
    "first_name": "Abdul",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/B01.png",
    "person_id": "556431f3cdfa6611083257f6",
    "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1b94"
  }, {
    "username": "M_Kennedy",
    "social_net_id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1952",
    "last_name": "Hugh",
    "first_name": "Beale",
    "avatar": "/media/avatars/B02.png",
    "person_id": "556431f3cdfa6611083257f7",
    "id": "55641120cdfa6618acdd1b96"
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "source": "0",
    "target": "1",
    "weight": 1.5
  }, {
    "source": "2",
    "target": "0",
    "weight": 26.5
  }, {
    "source": "0",
    "target": "2",
    "weight": 16.0
  }, {
    "source": "2",
    "target": "1",
    "weight": 1.5
  }]
}];

/*
 * refresh graph based on given data
 */
var refreshForceFlow = (function() {
  // Need to use a single instance of force because of
  // this bug https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2468
  // hence the closure...
  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)

  return function(json) {
    //    clearGraphFlow();  ***d3 does this for you if you do it right***
    //    var maxWeight = 0;
    //***this code is already written for you: you just need to wire it up***
    //    for(var edgeIndex = 0; edgeIndex < json.edges.length; edgeIndex++){
    //      if(json.edges[edgeIndex].weight > maxWeight) maxWeight = json.edges[edgeIndex];
    //    }
    var maxWeight = d3.max(json.edges, function(d) {
      return d.weight
    });
    //clean up the data: force needs type Number on link.source/destination
    json.edges.forEach(function(d) {
      d.source = +d.source;
      d.target = +d.target
    });
    console.log(json);

    force
      .nodes(json.nodes) //***don't need to wrap in d3.value***
      .links(json.edges)
      .on("tick", tickFlow)
      .start();

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    // UPDATE
    var defs = svg.selectAll("defs").data([json.edges]);
    // EXIT
    defs.exit().remove();
    // ENTER
    defs.enter().append("defs");
    // UPDATE+ENTER for defs
    // UPDATE for markers
    var markers = defs.selectAll("marker")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d
      }); //get the data elements from the defs datum
    //ENTER
    markers.enter().append("marker") //new markers only
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 13) //  15
      .attr("refY", 0) //  -1.5
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path");
    // UPDATE+ENTER
    markers.attr("id", function(d) {
        return ("weight_" + d.weight).replace(".", "_");
      })
      .select("path")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        var color = 'FF';
        var c = Math.floor((d.weight * 99) / maxWeight);
        c = 100 - c;
        if (c < 10) c = '0' + c;
        color = c + color;
        color = c + color;
        //console.log('#'+color);
        return '#' + color;
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        var color = 'FF';
        var c = Math.floor((d.weight * 99) / maxWeight);
        c = 100 - c;
        if (c < 10) c = '0' + c;
        color = c + color;
        color = c + color;
        //console.log('#'+color);
        return '#' + color;
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
    // EXIT
    markers.exit().remove();

    var link = svg.selectAll("g.link").data(force.links());
    link.enter().insert("g", ".link").attr("class", "link")
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link flow"); //***don't need a function for constant value***;
    link.exit().remove();
    path = link.select("path")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        var res = 1 + ((d.weight * 2.5) / maxWeight);
        return Math.round(res) + 'px';
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        var color = 'FF';
        var c = Math.floor((d.weight * 99) / maxWeight);
        c = 100 - c;
        if (c < 10) c = '0' + c;
        color = c + color;
        color = c + color;
        //console.log('#'+color);
        return '#' + color;
      })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#" + ("weight_" + d.weight).replace(".", "_") + ")";
      });

    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(force.nodes()), //node is the node container: includes circle and text
      nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").call(force.drag),
      //append the circle and the text inside the node g
      //ENTER
      circle = nodeEnter.attr("class", "node")
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 6)
      .attr("class", "flow"),
      //  .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu)),

      text = nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", "flow")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", ".31em")
      .style({
        "pointer-events": "all",
        cursor: "default"
      }) //***include dragging by text***

    //ENTER+UPDATE
    text.text(function(d) {
      return d.username;
    });

    // EXIT
    node.exit().remove();

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tickFlow(e) {
      path.attr("d", linkArc);
      node.attr("transform", transform); //circle and text is wrapped by node
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
      var tx = d.target.x - 0;
      var ty = d.target.y - 0;
      var sx = d.source.x - 0;
      var sy = d.source.y - 0;

      var dx = tx - sx,
        dy = ty - sy,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
  }; //  end of function
})();

/*
 * clear gragh
 */
//  var clearGraphFlow = function(){  // ***Not required***
//    svg.selectAll("g").remove();
//    svg.selectAll("defs").remove();
//  };

refreshForceFlow(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData[0])));
```

```css
body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    svg {
      outline: 1px solid red;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    .link.flow {
      opacity: 1!important;
      /*stroke-width: 1.5px;*/
    }
    #licensing {
      fill: green;
    }
    .link.flow.licensing {
      stroke: green;
    }
    .link.flow.resolved {
      stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
    }
    circle.flow {
      fill: #ff2575;
      stroke: #ff2575;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    text.flow {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      pointer-events: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    }
    path.link.flow {
      fill: none;
      stroke: blue;
    }
    div#panel {
      display: block;
    }
    input {
      margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <input id="update" type="button" value="update">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the urls are not valid.
Replace this...

```
.attr("id", function(d) { return d.weight; })
```

with this...

```
.attr("id", function(d) { return ("weight_"+d.weight).replace(".","_"; })
```

Comment: I just did what you suggested but it does not work yet. If you run code snippet here you will see that it works here! but I don't know what is wrong with my project that prevent the URLs references to work.

Comment: @rezCash, how are you getting the edge data `json.edges`?  It would help a lot if you could update your post so that the d3 code is a working example.

Comment: I just updated the snippet. It is not exactly my project because I use angularjs and so many angular services in my project but this is what I make this force layout in my project.